# How to share video from UIActivityViewController on twitter

Tags: ios, video, twitter, uiactivityviewcontroller

I want share text,image,link and video(Anything from these) on social networks.I shared text,link and image successfully. I have Urls for videos and images.I did googling and find that to we can share video which we have locally.so first I download video from that url and attach a video in uiactivityitem. My problem I am not able to share video on twitter,it's not showing twitter option to share but working fine for facebook.

my code is

```
NSString *sharestrurl=@"http://exmaple.com/abc.mp4";
NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

NSString *filextension=@"mp4";
NSString *filetitle=@"abc";

NSString *destinationFilename =[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.%@",filetitle,filextension];

NSURL *destinationURL = [self.docDirectoryURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:destinationFilename];

NSURL *ShareURL=destinationURL;

if ([fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[destinationURL path]]) {
            NSLog(@"file exist");

            sharedObjects = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObjects:@"Hey, check out this business! It is awesome!",ShareURL,nil];

 }else{

            SHOWALERT(@"Please download video before share");

}

UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc]  initWithActivityItems:sharedObjects applicationActivities:nil];


    activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[
                                                     UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList,
                                                     UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                                     UIActivityTypePrint,
                                                     UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                                     UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard,
                                                     UIActivityTypeAirDrop
                                                     ];


    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
    });
```

Comment: did you found any solution to this ?

Comment: In twitter we can't share video with UIActivityViewController. One possible thing is that you can share video by link of video in twitter post